# VSTS buildagent: Java 9

Tags: java, azure-devops, capability, build-agent

I installed the latest java sdk (included jre) version 9.0.1 on my buildserver and restarted the agents. The agent does not seem to detect Java, the java-capabilities are missing and builds won't run because the java-capability is not set on the agent.

Is there anything i have to do to get java recognized ? the last java 8.* version was propery recognized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on `[agent folder]\bin\Add-JavaCapabilities.ps1`, there are JDK 6,7,8, no JDK 9, so it can’t recognize JDK 9. I submit a user voice here: [VSTS build agent capabilities for JAVA 9](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31984054-vsts-build-agent-capabilities-for-java-9), you can vote it.

You can try to add capability manually:

1. Go to agent pool admin page (`https://XXX.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool`)
2. Select the pool and agent
3. Click Add capability

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: The default jvm is 11. You can use the level compatibility if your project works as well.**

The default version is 1.8. 
You can select the version: Maven build > Advanced > JDK Version

[image]

Comment: That is correct but requires that this java version is installed on the buildserver. There is now also a 'Java tool installer' to install/ensure the desired java version is installed/cached so there is no need to care about the capabilities-issues anymore anyway... The correct approach is now to have the java-tool-installer before the maven task or whatever you are using that requires java

Comment: I have used VSTS self-hosted Ubuntu 16 and it has this with zero additional installation, maybe because I'm using just JRE, I will test it

Comment: the hosted ubuntu image has the jdks 7 through 11 installed (according to their documentation), at the time of me writing this issue the situation with the hosted agents wasn't as good as it is now

Comment: I got it and changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting my agent it worked. The new capabilities start reflecting in system capabilities